# Turbo stream append works but does not change web page. defaultPrevented is true on it's own on frame element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails, turbo, turbo-rails

I'm following the original tutorial of turbo at https://hotwired.dev/

and I got to the point of 5:30, and when he added turbo like this:

div to update

```html
<div class="messages">
   <%= render @room.messages %>
</div>
```

```rb
def create
    @message = @room.messages.create!(message_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream
      format.html { redirect_to room_url(@room) }
    end
  end
```

and in `messages/create.turbo_stream.erb`
`<%= turbo_stream.append "messages", @message %>`

I opened browser page reloaded it, made a new comment and it did not work.
Nothing happens.
I opened logs, they seem to be fine

```
22:37:26 web.1  | Started POST "/rooms/4/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-03-26 22:37:26 +0200
22:37:26 web.1  | Processing by MessagesController#create as TURBO_STREAM
22:37:26 web.1  |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "message"=>{"conten"=>"123"}, "commit"=>"submit", "room_id"=>"4"}
22:37:26 web.1  |   Room Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
22:37:26 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:22:in `set_room'
22:37:26 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
22:37:26 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:10:in `create'
22:37:26 web.1  |   Message Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("room_id", "conten", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["room_id", 4], ["conten", "123"], ["created_at", "2023-03-26 20:37:26.059675"], ["updated_at", "2023-03-26 20:37:26.059675"]]
22:37:26 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:10:in `create'
22:37:26 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (3.1ms)  COMMIT
22:37:26 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:10:in `create'
22:37:26 web.1  |   Rendering messages/create.turbo_stream.erb
22:37:26 web.1  |   Rendered messages/_message.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 34)
22:37:26 web.1  |   Rendered messages/create.turbo_stream.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 248)
22:37:26 web.1  | Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms | Allocations: 3861)
```

and network tab in dev tools (using firefox, tested in IE and chrome)
it looks perfectly fine with resopnce as expected

```
<turbo-stream action="append" target="messages"><template>  <p id="message_50">
    26 Mar 20:37: 123
  </p>
</template></turbo-stream>
```

I found out that something can be wrong with turbo side
I added

```js
document.addEventListener('turbo:before-fetch-response', function(event) {
  console.log("Turbo loaded", event)
})
```

```
Turbo loaded 
turbo:before-fetch-response { target: form, isTrusted: false, detail: {…}, srcElement: form
, currentTarget: HTMLDocument http://127.0.0.1:3000/rooms/4, eventPhase: 3, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, returnValue: true, defaultPrevented: false, … }
​bubbles: true
​cancelBubble: false
​cancelable: true
composed: true
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: true
```

for some reason `defaultPrevented: true` is true
you can notice, that from the dispatch to log, something prevented it.

I found it debugging it

```js
 this.inspectFetchResponse = event => {
      const response = fetchResponseFromEvent(event);
      if (response && fetchResponseIsStream(response)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.receiveMessageResponse(response);
      }
    };
```

I have no idea what it do.

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

I tried to

```rb
format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append(:messages, partial: "message", locals: { message: @message }) }
```

but it didn't work
I also changed id of div to something more uniq, didn't work either

anyone knows what's wrong with it?

Comment: turbo stream `target` must be an `id`, not a `class`, like this: `<div id="messages"></div>`

Comment: That is the solution! Thank you! Can you create an answer, so that I could mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [tutorial](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/introduction):

> Turbo Streams introduces a `<turbo-stream>` element with seven basic actions: `append`, `prepend`, `replace`, `update`, `remove`, `before`, and `after`. With these actions, along with the `target` attribute specifying the ID of the element you want to operate on, you can encode all the mutations needed to refresh the page

and another [reference](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams):

> Turbo Streams deliver page changes as fragments of HTML wrapped in self-executing `<turbo-stream>` elements. Each stream element specifies an action together with a target ID to declare what should happen to the HTML inside it

It means you need add `id="messages"` attribute to your `<div class="messages">` to make it updatable